# ESP8266 dual Wifi communication

Tags: esp8266

I can make ESP8266 module to be connected to wifi hotspot. WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);
I also made the module to run as wifi hotspot with it's own ip, make it as webserver as well. 
Now how can I use a single esp8266 module to be connected to external wifi hotspot to send sensor data periodically? At the same time it will act as wifi hotspot so that another client pc/laptop can connect to this hotspot and get the webpage using its static IP?

Comment: and where is the problem? write a sketch with both functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send the data as well as use it as a web server you will need to have a include MDNS.

```
MDNS.begin("esp8266");
server.on("/", handleRoot);
server.begin();
```

Now you will have to create the function for handleRoot

```
void handleRoot() {
  int sec = millis() / 1000;
  int min = sec / 60;
  int hr = min / 60;

  snprintf(temp, 1000, 
"<html>\
  <head>\
    <title>YOUR_TITLE</title>\
    <style>\
      body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
    </style>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\
  </body>\
</html>", hr, min % 60, sec % 60);
  server.send(200, "text/html", temp);
}
```

This will show a web-page with time every-time you open the static ip of the esp8266.

Define the header file and later on include it in your code as

```
#ifndef htmlData_h
#define htmlData_h

const char* dataHTML = "MY HTML CODE";
const char* dataHTML1 = "MY 2 HTML CODE";
#endif
```

Example HTML code

```
const char* dataHTML = "<html>\
  <head>\
    <title>Demo</title>\
    <style>\
      body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
    </style>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h1>Hello!!!</h1>\
    <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\
    <FORM METHOD=POST action='/'>\
     <textarea rows = \"5\" cols = \"60\" name=myText>Talk to me...</textarea>\
     <br>\
     <input type=submit value='Talk'>\
   </FORM>\
  </body>\
</html>";
```

In the above code the page will give a text box which you have to use for sending the data to the esp8266 after you click on input button Talk displayed.

For printing the values use

`<input type=text name=myssid value=\"%s\">\`

and use

`snprintf(temp, 1000, dataHTML, variable1, varriable2,.....);`

here the variable1, variable 2 will represent all the %s values in sequence you have coded.

Comment: How it works? 
    <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\
</html>", hr, min % 60, sec % 60);

Comment: In simple terms the snprintf functions first creates a string and replaces the %02d with hr and so on... and then the "server.send" function send the whole data and display it on the web.

Comment: In the beginning of the function you will find : 
int sec = millis() / 1000;
 which converts the millis to seconds

Comment: Also you can use the form action in the web page and trigger the function you want.

Comment: I used Raw string literal to get html code. How can I use sprintf function to print variable in html code? 
[code]
char html_page[]= R"RAW(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<label for="ssid"> WiFi SSID</label>
<input type="text" name="ssid" value="" id="ssid" placeholder="SSID" />
</body>
</html>
)RAW";
server.send(200,"text/html",page);
[/code]

Comment: gives error - 
cannot convert 'String*' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'int snprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, ...)'

Comment: Use const char* for creating the html page.

Comment: Following code doesn't show any error. Upload to ESP is also successful. But ESP continues to restating. Without the snprintf function it is ok. 

int sec = millis() / 1000;
  int min1 = sec / 60;
  int hr = min1 / 60;
const char dataHTML[]=R"RAW(
<html>
<body>
<p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>
</body>
</html>
)RAW";

//, hr, min % 60, sec % 60);
 snprintf(page, 1000,dataHTML,sec,min1,hr);
 Serial.println(ssids_page);
  server.send(200, "text/html", page);

Comment: Have you used a delay in the loop

Comment: In which loop I need to add delay?

Comment: in the main loop

Comment: and MDNS.begin("esp8266");
server.on("/", handleRoot);
server.begin(); should be called via setup function and not in the loop function